# how to update variable using changeNotifierProxyProvider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

I am trying to update my header when I retry my API upon 401 response I am able to retry but my header is taking the previous value but not updated value

following is my changeNotifierProxyProvider

```
 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ApiCalls>(
            create: (_) => ApiCalls(),
            update: (context, auth, previous) => previous!..updates(auth)),
```

following is my auth class where I am updating my token

```
class Auth extends ChangeNotifier {
String? accessToken;
  DateTime? accessTokenExpiryDate;
String? get token {
    if (accessTokenExpiryDate != null &&
        accessTokenExpiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        accessToken != null) {
      return accessToken;
    } else if (accessTokenExpiryDate!.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      return accessToken;
    }
    return null;
  }

Future<void> restoreAccessToken() async {
    final url = '${Ninecabsapi().urlHost}${Ninecabsapi().login}/$sessionId';

    var response = await http.patch(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': accessToken!
      },
      body: json.encode(
        {"refresh_token": refreshtoken},
      ),
    );
    var userDetails = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      print(userDetails['messages']);
    }

    sessionId = userDetails['data']['session_id'];
    accessToken = userDetails['data']['access_token'];
    accessTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['access_token_expiry']),
    );
    refreshToken = userDetails['data']['refresh_token'];
    refreshTokenExpiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
      Duration(seconds: userDetails['data']['refresh_token_expiry']),
    );
    final userData = json.encode({
      'sessionId': sessionId,
      'refreshToken': refreshToken,
      'refreshExpiry': refreshTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String(),
      'accessToken': accessToken,
      'accessTokenExpiry': accessTokenExpiryDate!.toIso8601String()
    });


    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    prefs.setString('userData', userData);
    reset();
  }

}
```

following is my class where I wanted to call an api with updated token

```
class ApiCalls extends ChangeNotifier {
String? token;
void updates(Auth token) {
    this.token = token.token;
  }
Future<void> sample(BuildContext context, String s) async {
    print('sample:$token');

    var data = {"s": s, "filename":s};
    Map<String, String> obj = {"attributes": json.encode(data).toString()};

    var flutterFunctions =
        Provider.of<FlutterFunctions>(context, listen: false);
    final url =su().urlHost + su().getvehicle;
    try {
      loading();
      var response = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(url))
        ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
            "imagefile", flutterFunctions.imageFile!.path,
            contentType: MediaType("image", "jpg")))
        ..headers['Authorization'] = token!
        ..fields.addAll(obj);
      final client = RetryClient(
        http.Client(),
        retries: 1,
        when: (response) {
          return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
        },
        onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) async {
          //print('retry started $token');
          if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
            // Only this block can run (once) until done
            await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                .restoreAccessToken();
            req.headers['Authorization'] = token!;
            // extractData['accessToken']

            print('retry started ${req.headers['Authorization']}');
            //req.headers.clear();

          }
        },
      );
      final send = await client.send(response);
      final res = await http.Response.fromStream(send);
      
      var messages = json.decode(res.body);

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I had tried different methods but no one worked I had tried to call token directly from shared preference but it dint work I am attaching response please check
[image: you can see invalid token in my response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `notifyListeners` schedules the notification for the next frame. Internally, what `notifyListeners` simply does is to mark the widget as dirty ([`markNeedsBuild`](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/lib/src/inherited_provider.dart#L571-L579)) so the listeners get rebuilt on the next frame only. We can say that `notifyListeners` is asynchronous.

So, even though you await `Auth.restoreAccessToken` in the `ApiCalls.sample`, only in the next frame does the call to `ApiCalls.updates` occurs. But this `await` is longer done and the token is still the same as before for the retry.

To fix it just return the token from the `Auth.restoreAccessToken` in a `Future`. Something like the below code snippet:

```dart
token = await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
    .restoreAccessToken();
```

And there is no need to listen to `Auth` updates anymore.

Comment: hello thx for replying actually as you said I am trying to return my token in restoreAccessToken() but I am facing A value of type 'String' can't be returned from the method 'restoreAccessToken' because it has a return type of 'Future<void>'

Comment: your thought was not bad but if possible can you tell me how can we achieve this task using proxy provider

Comment: It's not possible. I'd recommend you then to get the token with `Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).token`

Comment: without runnining 'restoreAccessToken() I can't get updated token

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it

Comment: with out running  if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
            // Only this block can run (once) until done
            await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                .restoreAccessToken(); i cant get updated token from Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).token

Comment: No no... run the `restoreAccessToken` and then get the updated token with `Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).token`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247945/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-and-lepsch).